# setLayoutParams on Inherited View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, inherited-resources

Am having trouble with my android application. I wanna create a new View by doing this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainActivity);
    f = new InheritedView(this);
    f.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    l.addView(f);
}
```

With

```
public class InheritedView extends ImageView implements AbstractView 

public InheritedView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

But when I test that, my app crash with java.lang.StackOverflowError when executing setLayoutParams(..).
However, the following works :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainActivity);
    f = new ImageView(this);
    f.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    l.addView(f);
}
```

LOGCAT File

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fr.cameleoz.nemo, PID: 30304
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at fr.cameleoz.nemo.business.factories.nemoviews.impl.InheritedView.setLayoutParams(InheritedView.java:32)
            at [...]

Can you explain me why?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried to switch the addView and setLayoutParams line?

Comment: I have. It crashes beacause of the lack of essential parameters I guess...

Comment: There's got to be something coming up in the logcat.  An app won't just crash for no reason.

Comment: True! I've got an java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: I didn't instanciate f with the same Class in the working/not working. There's the difference : new InheritedView(this) / new ImageView(this).

Comment: Looks like you're overridden `setLayoutParams()` with a version that recursively calls itself until the stack is exhausted. Please post more of your custom class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace, your `InheritedView` overrides `setLayoutParams()` and the overridden method calls itself.

Each nested method call takes up some stack space and this infinite recursion only gets terminated when the stack runs out.

Comment: True! I would have never thought... Thank you very much!